# Forcing to append text to the end of a file name with .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

Currently i have this directory:

- example.com/curriculums/34-william.pdf
- example.com/curriculums/168-romina.pdf

34-william.pdf and 168.romina.pdf are actual files, and they do exist, but they should **only** be accesible if accessed using these urls:

- example.com/curriculums/34-william-cv.pdf
- example.com/curriculums/168-romina-cv.pdf

So that:

- If a visitor opens example.com/curriculums/34-william.pdf it should return a 404 response code
- If a visitor opens example.com/curriculums/34-william-cv.pdf the server should return the contents of example.com/curriculums/34-william.pdf

Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you don't have any .htacecss inside `curriculums` directory, you may use these rules inside your site root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteRule ^curriculums/[\w-]+(?<!-cv)\.\w+$ $1$2 [L,NC,R=404]

RewriteRule ^(curriculums/[\w-]+)-cv(\.\w+)$ $1$2 [L,NC]
```

Comment: Worked fine. Thanks!